# Method for storing users' photos in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, file

I am making a site where users have their own photos and I've seen a "controversy" over the decision of either storing photos as BLOBS in MYSQL (which apparently is slow?) vs some type of file system. I have made an example type program with blobs which was relatively easy but when I make the actual site I don't want anything slowing it down.

What is the most common way for storing photos?

What is this "file system" I think is what people are using?

Comment: Check [Storing Images in DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: @Ares Thanks I searched earlier but didn't find it. Post an answer so I can accept?